# How to add an EventListener to dynamically created button inside a parent id in PURE JAVASCRIPT , No Jquery

Tags: javascript

Suppose, I have a parent division(ul) in HTML.

Inside it, many dynamically generated list (li) is generated by JS code, having a class & an attribute.

I want to add on click events to those dynamically generated lists to fetch their respective attributes in pure javascript.

This Jquery Code works fine ->

```
$('#parentDivId').on('click','.dyanmicallyGeneratedChildClass',function(event){

   var child_attr = $(this).attr('dyanmicallyGeneratedChildClassAttr');

   console.log(child_attr); 

});
```

Can there be any alternative solution to the above code in pure Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a code writing service. We're glad to help with a problem you're having, but we expect you to make some effort (including searching this site and Google for existing answers) to solve it yourself first. The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), can help you become more familiar with this site and how it works.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't realize my code snippet didn't reflect properly .I have corrected it.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName`? Or maybe introduce a new `class` and `document.getElementsName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in jQuery is Event Delegation. You can do the same in the following way without using jQuery

```js
document.getElementById('division').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var liElement = event.target;
   if (liElement.className == 'dyanmicallyGeneratedChildClass' ) {
      console.log(liElement.getAttribute('dyanmicallyGeneratedChildClassAttr'));
    }
});
```

```html
<ul id="division">
    <li>bar </li>
    <li>abc </li>
    <li>123 </li>
    <li class="dyanmicallyGeneratedChildClass" dyanmicallyGeneratedChildClassAttr="test">foo </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: worked perfectly! so, event.target was the trick to select the particular list.